# Issue while using "Contact_Service" package to get contacts to phone in One format only

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-contacts

Anyone have experince or face  following issue while using "Contact_Service" package to get contacts to phone..

This package gives us  all our contact but when i want to get phone number of any contact, it gives in different format like +92, 0340, +91, 00012 etc. It gives format according to which its saved....But I want all phone numbers to be in One same format that's is International Format starting from "+". So if number is saved with 0340...it should convert it to +92340
Did any of you faced this issue while dealing with contacts of phone

Answer (score 0):

You solve your issue by adding +92 to the number that come from Contact_Service

Such like this

```
yourNumber="+65435435"
number="+92$yourNumber"
```